# A and B are enemies, B and C are enemies, what is the relationship between A and C?

Tags: logic

**Suppose the relationship between any pair among A,B,C are either friends or enemies.**

Question:
If A and B are enemies, B and C are enemies, what is the relationship between A and C? Are they enemies or friends? how to express these kind of question using mathematics symbols so that it is easier to think?

It is easy that if A,B are friends, B,C are friends, then A,C are also friends.

Comment: I think it would be possible that $A,C $ are friends, are enemies or have no defined relationship. Are you relating this to the real world? Or is it just from a purely mathematical point of view?

Comment: *if A,B are friends, B,C are friends, then A,C are also friends* - are you sure that's true? Being friends is not generally transitive.

Comment: In real life, friendship is not transitive, hence the saying "the enemy of my enemy is my friend" is not necessarily true

Comment: Are you sure that a friend of my friend is my friend ?

Comment: @RSerrao mathematical world

Comment: If the rule "the enemies of my enemies are my friends" holds, then $A$ and $C$ are friends. Otherwise you can't say.

Comment: Only if friendship (and enmity) is transitive.  Despite what social media programmers may insist the friend of your friend is not necessarily your friend.

Comment: "It is easy that if A,B are friends, B,C are friends, then A,C are also friends": no it's not "easy", it is undefined as long as you don't state it as a formal rule, which you cannot prove.

Comment: After the edit: If there are only two colours, then $A$ and $C$ are friends. If there are more than two colours, then $A$ and $C$ may be friends or enemies. (And if there are less than two colours, the situation cannot occur)

Comment: @ajcr suppose the relationship between any two are either friends or enemies. No pairs are indifference

Comment: Your colour idea only solves this if (a) friendship is transitive and (b) there are only two colours. Knowing A is red and B is blue and C is not blue does not tell you whether  C is red or green

Comment: @Henry see the bold text.

Comment: @fizis: I did read the bold text, but it does not decide the question, and you need more information.  Assuming friendship is transitive would give you your "if A,B are friends, B,C are friends, then A,C are also friends".  But if there can be more than two equivalence classes/colours (i.e. no assumption that enmity is anti-transitive) then you still cannot answer your question "If A and B are enemies, B and C are enemies, what is the relationship between A and C? "

Comment: @Henry the bold text has already tells you that friendship is transitive, no need to assume.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come up this analogy which I think is very intuitive: suppose if two people's favorite color are same, they are friends; otherwise they are enemies.

Therefore, if A, B are enemies, it can be that A like yellow, B like red. B,C are enemies, it can be that C like yellow or pink. Therefore the relationship between A and C is undefined.

On the contrary, if A,B are friends, then it can be they both like red; B,C are friends, they must both also like red. Therefore, A,C also both like red hence they are friends.

Answer (score 1):

I would suppose the symbols used depend on what you want to define. If I define that a relationship as an equivalence relation, then $X $ and $Y $ are friends iff $X \equiv Y $. But equivalence relations are transitive and then $X \equiv Y \wedge Y \equiv Z \Rightarrow X \equiv Z $.

So a friend of my friend would be my friend.

But this way I **forced** the friendship to be transitive because I assumed it was an *equivalence relation*.

Note however that $X \not\equiv Y \wedge Y \not\equiv Z $ says nothing about the relation between $X $ and $Z $.

Nonetheless, in real world friendship is not transitive, like pointed out in the comments. Actually, I am not really fond of my best friend's best friend.

Comment: However you are not enemies? So you are friends, because indifference is not allowed.

Comment: @fizis that depends on how much I think I dislike her. Some days it looks like we could be friends. Some other days I can't stand her.